# Download HTML file from URL using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am getting a URL in response. I want to download the html of that URL so that user can see it offline also. Its a recyclerView in which each items contain a URL. So when user clicks on the URL of one item it should save it in external disk.

Below is the code:

NewsAdapter:

```
case R.id.save:
                        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                                .setLenient()
                                .create();
                        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl("https://www.nytimes.com/")
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                                .build();
                        Log.i("Retrofit build", "initiated");
                        ApiInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

                                final Call< ResponseBody > call = retrofitInterface.downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync("2017/09/13/us/nursing-home-deaths-florida.html");

                        Log.i("Retrofit req execute", "initiated");

                            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                @Override
                                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                                    boolean writtenToDisk = false;
                                    try {
                                        writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(call.execute().body());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    ;

                                    Log.d("success", "file download was a success? " + writtenToDisk);
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }.execute();


                        break;

 private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
        try {
            // todo change the file location/name according to your needs
            File futureStudioIconFile = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + File.separator + "Future Studio Icon.png");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

                long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                    Log.d("filedownload", "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
                }

                outputStream.flush();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

ApiInterface:

```
// option 2: using a dynamic URL
@Streaming
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(@Url String fileUrl);
```

I am also getting the error:

```
Failed to invoke public com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody() with no args
```

Can someone tell me how to implement it correctly.

Comment: "2017/09/13/us/nursing-home-deaths-florida.html"   . prefix domian name to download file.

Answer (score 2):

Use URL with domain name to download file.Remove streaming annotation don't need that.

You are not receiving file body as you are not using complete URL.

Create an interface like this

```
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Url String url);
```

Then use this code :

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> 
response) 
                        {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                String filePath = Utils.downloadFile(response.body(),"filename");

                            }
                        }



public String downloadFile(ResponseBody body, String fileName) {
    String filePath = null;
    try {
        int count;
        byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
        InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AppName");
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File outputFile = new File(storageDir, fileName);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        bis.close();
        filePath = outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```